# How to prevent fractional text dimensions in Photoshop to be "pixel perfect"?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, text, typefaces, pixel

Is there any way to make Adobe Photoshop **text dimensions** (e.g. height and width) be **non-fractional**?

[image: Problem]

For example, if I use `Type` tool and just write my text on layout, it will have fractional dimensions. Of course I can use `Bounding box` to prevent this, but in this case I will need to manually adjust `Bounding box` size to meet real text size.

The result I want to achive is pretty simple: I  just want type my text and get it real dimension in pixels (not something like 65.69 px) to align it properly in my website layout.

Answer (score 2):

Surely, I must be missing something in this question...why not just manually enter the (whole) value of the font size you want?

- Transform your text to the size you'd like
- Enter the size you want in the highlighted box below

[image]

The reason your font might be defaulting to a decimal value is that it's likely the last font size you used.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply! No! Transforming text using "Transformation tool" is the worst practice in the world. My question is: how to avoid fractional text dimensions (not font size)?

Comment: See the image above!

Comment: @AlexMomotov _"Worst practice in the world"_ **Really?** A bit dramatic, don't you think? I'm confused what the issue is. Transform to a size close to that you want your font to be, then manually round to the nearest whole integer in the font-size box that I mentioned in my answer. Those dimensions in the upper toolbar you are looking at (which only appear when you _are_ using Free Transform) refer to the bounding box of the text, not the font-size, so it's irrelevant in web design anyway.  If you want to avoid fractions there, enter your values manually in those spaces...

Comment: @AlexMomotov also, I never use bounding boxes for text in photoshop. It's really cumbersome to size a box to your text (unless you have a very very specific layout). I prefer to size the text to fit the design. In case you don't know how to enter text without the bounding box: Click wherever you want your text to be while using the type tool (don't click and drag). Then resize like Manly shows in his answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought: try adjusting the kerning of your text to fit in the dimensions of a specific box.

In this example, I made a square artboard (200x200).

[image: Original text]

Now, use the keyboard shortcut for kerning to increase or decrease the space in between the letters. (alt+<- or ->)

[image: More kerning]

[image: Less kerning]

By adjusting kerning, you'll be able to fit your text into any size box you want. Hope this helps.